# Transaction log for database 'tempdb' is full due to 'ACTIVE_TRANSACTION

Tags: sql-server

I tried to shrink the log file but it only did small amount of free space.

The log space of tempdb is full due to the data file.
How can I free the space?

Edit:

I have checked following:
1. Bad queries are running - NO Queries are running

2. DBCC OPENTRAN - No Result
3. The tempdb is in SIMPLE recovery mode.
4. I have a separate drive for Transaction log of 1TB i.e. 40% free now.

Observation:
When I `Right click on tempdb>task>shrink>database` shows 99% free space available. Can I shrink the database file here?

Comment: Please consider doing some research first. If you have and still struggling consider telling us what issues you are struggling with exactly.

Comment: Currently I am going through the issue right now? I have no much idea other than the error message. I have skillset of SQL Development part. If you can share any related links, that would be helpful.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL SERVER Transaction log full](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132821/sql-server-transaction-log-full)

Answer (score 2):

Restarting the SQL instance will flush the tempdb and recreate it.